# CancellationToken not working in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, cancellation-token

I'm using Asp.net Core API and set services like bellow:

```
services
    .Configure<AppOptions>(_configuration.GetSection("app"))
    .AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
        })
    .AddFormatterMappings()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddCors();
```

After that, I created an API with a CancellationToken parameter like this:

```
[HttpGet("list")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await _orderBusinessService.GetList(cancellationToken);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

When I call this API from Postman or browser I getting below response:

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

When I added `[FromQuery]` to cancellationToken, It's OK.

Actually, that seems `CancellationTokenModelBinder` not working.

I don't know why?
Has anybody any ideas?

Comment: Im experiencing the same issue

Comment: Maybe can help: https://www.google.com/amp/s/andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/amp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your `Startup` class, and make sure you have the compatibility version set:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddApiExplorer()
    .AddAuthorization();
```

Adding that one line fixed the issue for me. (See https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/534#issuecomment-521680394 for the comment that pushed me in the right direction).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to use constructor injection instead of method. Removing it from the constructor and adding it as a parameter on the actions fixed it.